# Find a cell value in a list and select that cell form the list

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

I have a single value `CurrMon` on sheet "Hyperlinks" that I know is in a list on multiple different sheets. The range I need to find this in is always in `Range("V:V")` on each sheet. I have created a loop which goes down a list of values, the list of value is also my sheet name, it will select a cell, copy it then go to the correct sheet.

My next step, which I can't figure out, is I need to scan a list on this new sheet and select that cell, then paste my copied value one column to the right.

Each month the month will roll over so I will slowly build a list.

Below is my current loop which works up until the scanning a list for my `CurrMon` value.

```
Sub PlaceHyperlinks()

Worksheets("Hyperlinks").Activate

'CurrMon = Current Month
Dim CurrMon As String
CurrMon = Range("E1").Value

Dim cell As Range
Dim sht As String

Dim MonList As Range
Set MonList = Range("V2:V13")

For Each cell In Range("A10:A21")
    sht = cell.Value
    'copy hyperlink cell
    cell.Offset(, 3).Copy
    
    'go to target sheet
    Worksheets(sht).Activate

    'lookup date CurrMon from MonList
    'MonList.Select
    If CurrMon = MonList.Value Then
           MonList.Select
    End If

    'paste hyperlink in correct row
    
    
    'go back to Hyperlinks sheet
    Worksheets("Hyperlinks").Activate
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set MonList = Range("V2:V13")` sets the range **of the active sheet**. What do you expect from `If CurrMon = MonList.Value`? Should `currMon` be a string? Anyhow, MonList.Value returns an array... It would be good to edit your question and clearly explain **in words** what your code tries accomplishing. Looking to a not working piece of code and not knowing what you expect from it, is difficult to understand what is needed to help you. Maybe, some pictures will better clarify the issue, if looks more complicated to use words...

Comment: You can't compare a string to a range of cells, you need to loop through each cell or use FIND, MATCH or similar.

Comment: @SJR I am afraid that he thinks that `MonList` will automatically be reproduced in the sheet he is only activating. Should it need to activate the same `curMonth` in the same range, for each iterated sheet? Not sure about it, I only tried putting in his shoes looking to the code. That's why I asked about a clearer description of what he tries doing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The range I need to find* - use [Range.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub PlaceHyperlinks()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim cel As Range, fnd As Range
    Dim CurrMth As String, sht As String
    Dim lastrow As Long, n As Long
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    With wb.Sheets("Hyperlinks")

        'CurrMth = Current Month
        CurrMth = .Range("E1").Value
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        For Each cel In .Range("A10:A" & lastrow)
            sht = cel.Value
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ws = wb.Sheets(sht)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If ws Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "Sheet " & sht & " not found", vbCritical
                Exit Sub
            End If
            
            Set fnd = ws.Range("V:V").Find(CurrMth, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            If fnd Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox CurrMth & " not found on " & sht, vbCritical
                Exit Sub
            Else
                ' hyperlink in column W
                fnd.Offset(, 1).Value = cel.Offset(, 3)
                n = n + 1
            End If
            Set ws = Nothing
        Next
    End With
    MsgBox n & " links updated for " & CurrMth, vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. Here is the complete solution that also gave me the desired results. I was able to get to this with the `For Each moncell` part of the code.

This allowed me to find the month I had selected in `currmon` and then paste next to the same value in the range `V2:V13` on each sheet that I was lopping through.

```
Sub PlaceHyperlinks()

Worksheets("Hyperlinks").Activate

'CurrMon = Current Month
Dim CurrMon As String
CurrMon = Range("E1").Value

Dim cell As Range
Dim sht As String
Dim MonList As Range

For Each cell In Range("A10:A21")
    sht = cell.Value
    'copy hyperlink cell
    cell.Offset(, 3).Copy
    
    'go to target sheet
    Worksheets(sht).Activate
    Set MonList = Range("V2:V13")
    
    'lookup date CurrMon from MonList
    Dim moncell As Range
    For Each moncell In MonList
        If moncell = CurrMon Then
            moncell.Offset(, 1).PasteSpecial
        End If
    Next moncell
    
    'go back to Hyperlinks sheet
    Worksheets("Hyperlinks").Activate
Next cell

'clear copy selection
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Looked Up Value For Each Worksheet in a List

[image]

**Source**

- In the source worksheet `Hyperlinks`, I have a list of worksheet names in the range `A10:A_lr`.
- For each worksheet from the list, I need to copy the corresponding value in column `D`.
- I also have a **lookup value** in cell `E1`.

**Destination**

- In each destination worksheet, I have a list of values in the range `V2:V13`
- I need to find the **lookup value** in that range and, in the same row, paste the copied value to column `W`.

```vb
Sub CopyThisMonthsData()

    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "Hyperlinks"
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAMES_FIRST_CELL As String = "A10"
    Const SRC_LOOKUP_CELL As String = "E1" ' month
    Const SRC_RETURN_COLUMN As String = "D"
    
    Const DST_LOOKUP_RANGE As String = "V2:V13" ' 12 months
    Const DST_RETURN_COLUMN As String = "W"

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim slValue As Variant: slValue = sws.Range(SRC_LOOKUP_CELL).Value
    Dim srg As Range:
    With sws.Range(SRC_SHEET_NAMES_FIRST_CELL)
        Set srg = sws.Range(.Cells, sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    Dim slcell As Range, srcell As Range
    Dim dws As Worksheet, drg As Range, drcell As Range, drIndex As Variant
    
    For Each slcell In srg.Cells
        On Error Resume Next
            Set dws = wb.Sheets(CStr(slcell.Value))
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not dws Is Nothing Then
            Set drg = dws.Range(DST_LOOKUP_RANGE)
            drIndex = Application.Match(slValue, drg, 0)
            If IsNumeric(drIndex) Then
                Set srcell = slcell.EntireRow.Columns(SRC_RETURN_COLUMN)
                Set drcell = drg.Cells(drIndex) _
                    .EntireRow.Columns(DST_RETURN_COLUMN)
                ' Copy values, formats and formulas.
                srcell.Copy drcell
                ' Copy values only (more efficient).
                'drcell.Value = srcell.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next slcell

    MsgBox "This month's data copied.", vbInformation

End Sub
```